# Setting one item to true and others false mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving cards in my mongo db, but only one card can be the default card which would be set to true. When I set this card to true, every other card should be set to false. I have tried to update a query in mongoose but I just could not get the right query as query just updates the card I want as default but does not set others to false.

this is my function

```
const card = { ...fixedCard, isDefault: true };
await this.model.updateMany(
        { id: id },
        
        { $push: { cards: card } },
        { "cards.id": { $ne: fixedCard.id }, $set: { "cards.isDefault" : false } }
        
     );
```

This just adds the card but does not update the previous ones everything remains true. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the best to set all to false first and then set your one matched with id to true.

```
[
  {
    '$set': {
      'active': false
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '_id': new ObjectId('62fca902ced7baa13ae37866')
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'active': true
    }
  }
]
```